# Linker command failed with exit code 1 after moving project from one computer to another

Tags: objective-c, xcode, linker-errors

i am new to Xcode and obective-c and I have a problem with a project I have taken over from another developer on another machine. I cannot contact this programmer anymore (fired).

```
Ld /Users/*****/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Dino-eyvcyvuofjuafncdadqeywyvdsra/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/Dino.app/Dino normal i386
        cd /Users/******/Dropbox/Xcode/ABCiTY/Dino
        setenv IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET 5.1
        setenv PATH "/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/usr/bin:/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin"
        /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/clang -arch i386 -isysroot /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator6.1.sdk -L/Users/******/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Dino-eyvcyvuofjuafncdadqeywyvdsra/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator -F/Users/******/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Dino-eyvcyvuofjuafncdadqeywyvdsra/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator -filelist /Users/******/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Dino-eyvcyvuofjuafncdadqeywyvdsra/Build/Intermediates/Dino.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/Dino.build/Objects-normal/i386/Dino.LinkFileList -Xlinker -objc_abi_version -Xlinker 2 -ObjC -fobjc-arc -fobjc-link-runtime -Xlinker -no_implicit_dylibs -mios-simulator-version-min=5.1 -lABCityCrossMarketing -framework AdSupport -framework CoreMotion -framework SystemConfiguration -framework CoreData -framework QuartzCore -framework CoreImage -framework AVFoundation -framework StoreKit -framework UIKit -framework Foundation -framework CoreGraphics -lGoogleAnalytics -lGoogleConversionTracking -o /Users/*******/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Dino-eyvcyvuofjuafncdadqeywyvdsra/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/Dino.app/Dino

    ld: library not found for -lABCityCrossMarketing
    clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

Can anyone help me with this?

Comment: Perhaps Xcode did not copy the `ABCityCrossMarketing` library over, it just kept a reference to it in the project. You have to copy that library to the other computer to the same location.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The message is clear here, I think:

```
library not found for -lABCityCrossMarketing
```

This happens when you move folders and the controls or basically any file is misplaced by Xcode and it doesn't know where to find it. You'd have to add it to your project again or change the path to it wherever it was listed.

Answer (score 1):

You are missing the library file `libABCityCrossMarketing.a`.

A google for "ABCityCrossMarketing" returns nothing for me.  Looks bad.  If you still have access to his machine, then that looks like the only way to recover this file (it's possible this library was written by him and never published).